# Menu is going to get inline style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I got this page i need to make a change on, but i cant find the script who is going to make the inline style.. Its only on the mobile (dropdown menu)

`<div class="is-drilldown" style="height: 504px; width: 163.438px;"></div>`

http://kvejborg.dk/

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the script is `scripts/main.js`. But it is the output of an optimizer, so there will be some other files (maybe somewhere else), which are the source of that file. Often, these files are located in `/scripts` or `/src`.

Comment: Well. I know that. But i cant find where it is. I have been looking around in long time :S

Comment: The code is in line 3583 of main.js, so you could just search for one of the lines in the whole project (you could use `grep -r 'addClass("is-drilldown").css(this._getMaxDims()' .` if you are using Linux)

Comment: Well.. I can find it in the main, but i cant find it before i compile it all to an minified js file

Comment: Try to shorten the search string: `grep -r 'addClass("is-drilldown") .`

Comment: Then maybe you simply don't have the source code. Is there someone you got the project from and you may ask? It would not be very convenient to change directly in the generated file...